# Algorithm runnning time $T(n) = \sqrt{n} \cdot T(\sqrt{n}) + \sqrt{n} $ using substitution

Tags: asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

I need to solve the following recurrence, only using the [**substituion method** (CLRS)](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture3.pdf):

$$ T(n) = \sqrt n \cdot T(\sqrt n) + \sqrt n $$

This is what I have done so far:

1. Changing variables
   $$ m = \log_{2}n$$
   $$ n = 2^{m} $$
   $$ \log n = m $$
2. Updating the recurrence function, so that $T(2^{m}) = S(m)$

$$ T(2^{m}) = 2^\frac{m}{2} \cdot T(2^\frac{m}{2}) + 2^\frac{m}{2}$$
$$ S(m) = \frac{m}{2} \cdot T(\frac{m}{2}) + \frac{m}{2}$$

And then here, I'm not sure how to proceed nor if my argument is correct so far.

I tried to follow a similar example answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239402/solve-the-recurrence-relation-tn-sqrtn-t-left-sqrt-n-right-n), but I wasn't able to properly translate it.

Comment: Are you sure about $\sqrt n = m$? :) The substitutions $n = 2^m$ and $T(2^m) = S(m)$ are fine. First, write the correct recurrence relation for $S$ (why did $2^{m/2}$ outside of $T$ become $m/2$?). Then take $S(m) = 2^m F(m)$ and apply the master theorem.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks for pointing the mistake. $\log n = m$ should be. I have updated the question. I cannot use the Master Theorem here. Should be only by substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Go a little further with $n = 2^{2^m}$.
Since $\sqrt{2^{2^m}} = 2^{2^{m-1}}$, this becomes

$T(2^{2^m}) = 2^{2^{m-1}}T(2^{2^{m-1}})+2^{2^{m-1}}$.

Letting $T(2^{2^m}) = s(m)$, this becomes
$s(m) = 2^{2^{m-1}}s(m-1)+2^{2^{m-1}}$.

Dividing by $2^{2^{m}}$ this is

$\frac{s(m)}{2^{2^{m}}} = \frac{s(m-1)}{2^{2^{m-1}}}+\frac{1}{2^{2^{m-1}}}$.

Letting $u(m) = \frac{s(m)}{2^{2^{m}}}$, this becomes

$u(m) = u(m-1)+ \frac{1}{2^{2^{m-1}}}$.

$u(m)$ converges to a constant $c$, so
$s(m) \to c2^{2^{m}}$ so
$T(2^{2^m})  \to c2^{2^{m}}$
or $T(n) \to cn$.

Putting this into the original equation, we get
$cn = \sqrt{n}c\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}$
which is approximately true.

To get a more accurate answer, let 
$T(n) = c n+r(n)$ 
and see what you can find about
$r(n)$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I’m trying to understand. Why is it that $n = 2^{2^{m}} $ and not $n = 2^{m} $ instead as I wrote it in my question?

Comment: Because that works with $\sqrt$. $2^m$ works with t(n) = a t(n/2) and $b^m$ works with $t(n) = a t(n/b).

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Using another approach, intending to obtain a comparison result, with

$$
\mathcal{T}(\cdot) = T\left(4^{(\cdot)}\right), z = \log_4 n,\ \ \mathbb{T}(\cdot) = \mathcal{T}\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right),\ u = \log_2 z
$$

we obtain the recurrence

$$
\mathbb{T}(u)=2^{2^u}\mathbb{T}(u-1)+2^{2^u}
$$

with solution

$$
\mathbb{T}(u)= 4^{2^u}C_0+4^{2^u}\sum_{k=0}^{u-1}4^{-2^k}
$$

After returning to $T(n)$ we have

$$
T(n) = n C_0 + n\sum_{k=0}^{\log_2(\log_4 n)-1}4^{-2^k}
$$